# Builder/named argument/fluent interface pattern with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11, smart-pointers

I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to implement a fluent interface with `unique_ptr` and other "modern" C++ language constructs. Here's my first attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

// Backported from C++14
namespace std
{
    template<typename T, typename ...Args>
    std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args &&... args)
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
}

using namespace std;

class Widget
{
    Widget() = delete;
    Widget(Widget const &) = delete;
    Widget(Widget &&) = delete;
    Widget &operator=(Widget const &) = delete;
    Widget &operator=(Widget &&) = delete;

public:
    Widget(string const &name) :
        m_name(name)
    { }

    ~Widget()
    { }

    string const &name() const
    { return m_name; }

private:
    string const m_name;
};

class WidgetBuilder
{
    WidgetBuilder(WidgetBuilder const &) = delete;
    WidgetBuilder(WidgetBuilder &&) = delete;
    WidgetBuilder &operator=(WidgetBuilder const &) = delete;
    WidgetBuilder &operator=(WidgetBuilder &&) = delete;

public:
    WidgetBuilder()
    { }

    ~WidgetBuilder()
    { }

    WidgetBuilder &name(string const &name)
    { m_name = name; return *this; }

    unique_ptr<Widget> create()
    { return make_unique<Widget>(m_name); }

private:
    string m_name;
};

class WidgetContainer
{
    WidgetContainer() = delete;
    WidgetContainer(WidgetContainer const &) = delete;
    WidgetContainer(WidgetContainer &&) = delete;
    WidgetContainer &operator=(WidgetContainer const &) = delete;
    WidgetContainer &operator=(WidgetContainer &&) = delete;

public:
    WidgetContainer(
        string const &firstName,
        string const &lastName,
        unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<Widget>>> widgets) :
        m_firstName(firstName),
        m_lastName(lastName),
        m_widgets(move(widgets))
    { }

    ~WidgetContainer()
    { }

    string const &firstName() const
    { return m_firstName; }

    string const &lastName() const
    { return m_lastName; }

    vector<unique_ptr<Widget>> const &widgets() const
    { return *m_widgets; }

private:
    string const m_firstName;
    string const m_lastName;
    unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<Widget>>> m_widgets;
};


class WidgetContainerBuilder
{
    WidgetContainerBuilder(WidgetContainerBuilder const &) = delete;
    WidgetContainerBuilder(WidgetContainerBuilder &&) = delete;
    WidgetContainerBuilder &operator=(WidgetContainerBuilder const &) = delete;
    WidgetContainerBuilder &operator=(WidgetContainerBuilder &&) = delete;

public:
    WidgetContainerBuilder()
    { }

    ~WidgetContainerBuilder()
    { }

    WidgetContainerBuilder &firstName(string const &firstName)
    { m_firstName = firstName; return *this; }

    WidgetContainerBuilder &lastName(string const &lastName)
    { m_lastName = lastName; return *this; }

    WidgetContainerBuilder &addWidget(WidgetBuilder &widgetBuilder)
    {
        m_widgetBuilders.push_back(&widgetBuilder);
        return *this;
    }

    unique_ptr<WidgetContainer> create()
    {
        unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<Widget>>> widgets =
            make_unique<vector<unique_ptr<Widget>>>();
        for (auto &widgetBuilder : m_widgetBuilders)
        {
            widgets->push_back(widgetBuilder->create());
        }
        return make_unique<WidgetContainer>(
            m_firstName,
            m_lastName,
            move(widgets));
    }

private:
    string m_firstName;
    string m_lastName;
    vector<WidgetBuilder *> m_widgetBuilders;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unique_ptr<WidgetContainer> x(
        WidgetContainerBuilder()
            .firstName("my-first-name")
            .lastName("my-last-name")
            .addWidget(
                WidgetBuilder()
                    .name("my-widget-0"))
            .addWidget(
                WidgetBuilder()
                    .name("my-widget-1"))
            .create());

    cout << x->firstName() << " " << x->lastName() << endl;
    for (auto &widget : x->widgets())
    {
        cout << widget->name() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The requirements of the design is that the fully constructed objects of the `WidgetContainer` and `Widget` "final" types should be immutable: properties of these classes must only be settable during construction and unchangeable thereafter. In order to construct instances of these classes, I've written `WidgetContainerBuilder` and `WidgetBuilder`. The other constraint is that I need to be able to manage the lifetimes of the final types using `unique_ptr`.

The example I give here works and has no obvious bugs, as far as I can tell. However, I would be interested in feedback about potential issues or approaches I might take to improve the cleanliness or fluency of the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't do this:

```
using namespace std;
```

See: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065)

I would change a couple of things:

#### In WidgetBuilder

I don't like the explicit call to `create()` WidgetBuilder.

```
unique_ptr<Widget> create()
{ return make_unique<Widget>(m_name); }
```

I would replace it with a conversion operator:

```
operator std::unique_ptr<Widget>()
{    return std::make_unique<Widget>(m_name);}
```

Then usage becomes:

```
unique_ptr<Widget>  val = WidgetBuilder().name("Loki");
```

#### In WidgetContainer

I don't see the need to put the `std::vector` inside a `std::uniqu_ptr`.

```
unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<Widget>>> m_widgets;
```

I would just do

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Widget>>> m_widgets;
```

Because of RVO and NRVO this is very efficient when returning objects. Also with the use of "Move Semantic" even passing it as a parameter is now very efficient.

#### In WidgetContainerBuilder

Like WidgetBuilder remove the `create()` method.

Not sure I would pass `WidgetBuilder` to the `addWidget()` method. Why not a `std::unique_ptr<Widget>` create them on the fly and use them as needed. (I suppose this is why you had an explicit `create()` method on `Widget`.

```
WidgetContainerBuilder &addWidget(WidgetBuilder &widgetBuilder)
```

Comment: +1: Agree with you totally about `using namespace std` except when I'm prototyping like this. Thanks for the comments!